# Typescript ReturnType problem for generic class method

Tags: typescript, class, generics, return-type

I'm using typescript: 4.3.5

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Parent {
  public get<Type>(id: number): Observable<Type> {
    ...
  }
}
```

and a child class:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  public get<{id: number}>(id: number): Observable<{id: number}> {
    ...
  }
}
```

I cannot get the ReturnType of the get method for the child class

If i do this:

```
type T = ReturnType<Child['get']>;
```

I expect to get {id: string} but it does not work... I just get from my IDE:

```
<{id: string}>(id: number) => Observable<{id: string}> extends ((...args: any) => infer R) ? R : any
```

Is there a way to do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code works as is. There is no possible inference of `Type` from a `get` override in a child class which makes the code fail even before the `ReturnType` issue you are mentioning.

You should refactor your code like this:

```
abstract class Parent<Type> {
  public get(id: number): Type {
    // ...
  }
}

class Child extends Parent<Observable<{ id: number }>> {
  public get(id: number): Observable<{ id: number }> {
  }
}


type T = ReturnType<Child['get']>;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAngA64B8CA3gLABQCCFAriMgJawIDmuCAApuAEwBcCfOwC2IXFACUU8lXrNWrAPTaEAOkOaEAX2ZmmzFGgwBhABbdkYhLgAeEAmIzY8hIgDy4IoAbqDIuER0COJSMvKKptS0jCxsnDx8giKx0nIKylJBYKHhkdG58QVJGmkWFszMEJS4CCQIALwIAEpC7FD4apEOTmIA2gDk2RMAutQA3EA)

Comment: Worse - it's a _syntax_ error that is translated into _different_ kind of expression than we expect.  `{ id: number}` is not a valid _name_ for a type (e. g. `type { what: no } = any` isn't valid and neither is `public get<{ this: is.not.a.name }>()`.  The OP's syntax is being parsed as a _property_ with a generic anonymous function (not 100% sure why).

Comment: okay, let suppose I define a type:
`interface Person {
  id: number;
}`

And I define my Child as follow:
`class Child extends Parent {
  public get<Person>(id: number): Observable<Person> {
    ...
  }
}`
Then why: type Type = ReturnType<Child['get']> is not = Observable<Person> ?

Comment: It actually is: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN7LAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANzIC+AsAFDtw0ZhSJjIEAGzgYMaOFAjh87ZMgAOFGkOAJkAcwhgAPABUAngogA+ABTEylWtACUZAPLdoANy5CI+o6dkc281jZA9mFRcQBhAAtgISJkCAAPSBAicVRJaQECJRU1TW0ddChsEHNLcmo6KHtkJwxXd08ikpN8Znb2djBvZENjZABeZAAlbQooED7PKJiiAG0Aci0wBYBdEyA

Comment: Okay so the problem is from my IDE then thanks :-)